# Similar triangles eventually

Tags: triangles

Through the A-peak of the ABCD square is built a right that crosses the country BC at the point P. The bisector(bisectrix) of the angle PAD crosses the side to the point L. Find DL + BP  if AP = 5 cm[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the side of the square be $s = AD = AB$ and let $\theta = \angle DAL = \angle LAP$. Also let lengths $x = AP, y = DL$ and $z = BP$.

Then $\angle ABP = 90^\circ - 2\theta$. In the  right triangle
$ABP$  we have
$$
z = x \sin (90^\circ - 2\theta) = x \cos(2\theta)= x (1 - 2\sin^2\theta)
\\ s = x \cos(90^\circ - 2\theta) = x \sin(2\theta)= 2x \sin \theta \cos \theta
$$
And in right triangle $ADL$   we have
$$y = s\tan \theta = (2x\sin\theta \cos \theta) \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = 2x \sin^2 \theta
$$
Adding, 
$$
z+y = x(1 - 2\sin^2\theta)+2x\sin^2\theta=x
$$
In the problem given, $x = 5$ cm. so $AL + AP= z+y=x = 5$ cm.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $g$ be the angle $(\vec {AB},\vec {AP}) $ and $a=AB $.
then

$$\sin(g)=\frac {BP}{5} $$
and
$$\tan (g)=\frac {BP}{a} $$
on the other hand

$$\tan (\frac {90-g}{2})=\frac {DL}{a} $$